# How to get proper https server response in apache camel DSL?

Tags: apache, http-headers, apache-camel, dsl

I am trying to hit ***https*** server using ***https4*** component I want to get whatever response the server throwing it maybe ***success*** or ***failed*** here is my route.

```
from("direct:start")
   .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,constant("USERNAME=__&PASSWORD=__"))
   .to("https4://someAddress.com/api/controls/uploadAndImportFileFromCSV")
   .to("stream:out");
```

Output I'm getting:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-rajat-Lenovo-G50-70-1513247400372-0-1]
org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1847)
.........
Caused by: org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking https4://someAddress.com/api/controls/uploadAndImportFileFromCSV?USERNAME=__&PASSWORD=__ with statusCode: 599
```

But whenever I hit this URL on web browser I am getting the accurate response what server throws

***like***     {"sessionId":"2985416A1F1122694031261B55F0277F.jvm1","_ERROR_MESSAGE_LIST_":[" ***The following required parameter is missing:*** [IN]uploadAndImportFile.configId]","The following required parameter is missing: [IN][uploadAndImportFile.fileTypeEnumId]"],"removePathAlias":false,"loggedIn":true,"USERNAME":"admin","_LOGIN_PASSED_":"TRUE","webSiteId":"API"}

***This is what I want to get from camel***

Comment: Remove the setHeader and just try with this  
`.to("https4://someAddress.com/api/controls/uploadAndImportFileFromCSV?authMethod=Basic&authUsername=xxxx&authPassword=yyyyy)`

Comment: No changes @pvpkiran ***HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking https***

Comment: I think Since the request throw an exception, Camel is wrapping it in another exception. But in browser this doesn't happen because there is no camel so you see the exact exception.

Comment: try disabling the error handler for the route with this `.errorHandler(noErrorHandler())`. put this before .to(..)

Comment: No updates @pvpkiran

Comment: Yahh you were right @pvpkiran request throw an exception and camel wrapping it in another exception.Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a brief browsing about camel exception randomly I got my solution is already clearly mention on org.apache.camel.http4.

If **throwExceptionOnFailure=false** the HttpOperationFailedException will not be thrown for failed response codes. This allows you to get any response from the remote server.

```
from("direct:start")....to("https4://.......?throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
```